# How can i get the output of javascript object in div tag using document.write?

Tags: javascript, html, object, document.write

JavaScript Page:

I have created javascript function and inside it there is one object named Passenger which has three values i.e. name="A", age=30, reservationStatus=true. Now i want to print these values inside these three respective div's using document.write

HTML Page:

I have created three div tags with id="name", id="age", id="reservationStatus" and one button which has onclick event of javascript function.

Expected Results:

Name: A
Age: 30
Reservation Status: true

Comment: Hi Savita and welcome to SOF. Can you share with us your code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```js
window.onload = () => {

  const passenger = {
    name: 'A',
    age: 30,
    reservationStatus: true
  };

  const nameElement = document.querySelector('#name');
  const ageElement = document.querySelector('#age');
  const reservationStatusElement = document.querySelector('#reservationStatus');
  const btnShowPassengerElement = document.querySelector('#btnShowPassenger');

  // Hiding on window onload
  nameElement.innerHTML = '';
  ageElement.innerHTML = '';
  reservationStatusElement.innerHTML = '';

  btnShowPassengerElement.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    // Showing them on click of the button
    nameElement.innerHTML = passenger.name;
    ageElement.innerHTML = passenger.age;
    reservationStatusElement.innerHTML = passenger.reservationStatus;
  });

};
```

```css
group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnShowPassenger">Show Passenger Details </button>

<div>
  <div class="group">
    <div> Name: </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div id="name"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="group">
    <div> Age: </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div id="age"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="group">
    <div> Reservation Status: </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div id="reservationStatus"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document.getElementById() to identify an element with id(like div) and set a value to it as

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =Passenger.name;
document.getElementById("age").innerHTML =Passenger.age;
document.getElementById("reservationStatus").innerHTML =Passenger.reservationStatus;
```

Comment: I have already used this code, can you please share how can i print these value using document.write inside div tag?

Comment: document.write will not write inside a div, because there is no way it can recognize which div to write in

Answer (score 0):

```js
const passenger = {
  name: 'A',
  age: 30,
  reservationStatus: true,
};

const button = document.querySelector('button');

const showInfo = () => {
  document.querySelector('#name').textContent = `Name: ${passenger.name}`;
  document.querySelector('#age').textContent = `Age: ${passenger.age}`;
  document.querySelector('#reservationStatus').textContent = `Reservation status: ${passenger.reservationStatus}`;
};

button.addEventListener('click', showInfo);
```

```html
<button>Show</button>
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="age"></div>
<div id="reservationStatus"></div>
```